# Resolver problema de tabela com itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, itextsharp, itext

Preciso pegar a quantidade de produtos abaixo de x valor de uma tabela, porem deve ser por pagina, e a cada pagina que tiver ele deve pegar a quantidade da pagina atual + paginas passadas, existe uma maneira de fazer isso ?

Comment: siim provavelmente, mas junto a pergunta poderia dispor do codigo fonte?

Comment: inclua o codigo fonte para que todos possam analisar!

Answer (score -3):

Você pode percorrer as páginas do documento PDF gerado pelo iTextSharp e contar a quantidade de produtos abaixo de um determinado valor em cada página. Você pode armazenar a quantidade de produtos por página em uma variável acumuladora e somá-la a cada nova página percorrida. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

```
    // Valor limite para a quantidade de produtos abaixo de x valor
int valorLimite = 100;

// Variável acumuladora para a quantidade de produtos abaixo de x valor
int quantidadeTotal = 0;

// Criação do documento PDF com iTextSharp
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("caminho/do/arquivo.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

// Adicione aqui o código para gerar a tabela no documento PDF utilizando iTextSharp
// ...

// Percorre cada página do documento PDF
for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= writer.PageNumber; pageNumber++)
{
    // Obtém a página atual
    PdfPage page = writer.GetPageN(pageNumber);
    // Obtém o conteúdo da página
    PdfDictionary pageDict = page.GetAsDict(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    // Verifica se a página possui conteúdo
    if (pageDict != null)
    {
        // Lê o stream de bytes do conteúdo da página
        byte[] pageContentBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((PRStream) PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pageDict.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS)));

        // Decodifica o stream de bytes para uma string
        string pageContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pageContentBytes);

        // Adicione aqui o código para analisar o conteúdo da página e contar a quantidade de produtos abaixo de x valor
        // Utilize a variável acumuladora quantidadeTotal para somar a quantidade de produtos por página

    }
}

// Fecha o documento PDF
document.Close();
```

Observe que o exemplo acima é apenas um esqueleto de como você pode implementar a contagem da quantidade de produtos abaixo de um determinado valor por página utilizando o iTextSharp. O código específico para analisar o conteúdo da página e contar a quantidade de produtos pode variar dependendo da estrutura do seu documento PDF e do formato dos dados na tabela. Você pode precisar utilizar expressões regulares, manipulação de strings ou outras técnicas de análise de texto para extrair as informações corretas da tabela. Certifique-se de entender a estrutura do seu documento PDF e o formato dos dados para implementar a contagem corretamente.